# Where can I find the specifications for HTML select widget?

Tags: user-interface, widget, html-select, specifications

HTML select widget is very constrained in how it can be styled. To work around this, there are many libraries attempting to reimplementing it using JavaScript, but most lack one or another feature which is available in the native version. Here are a few features which are hard to find in a single implementation:

- arrow keys can be used to go through the options of a focused select element without opening the popup
- possible to jump to an option by typing letters it starts with
- the popup opens at the top if there's not enough space at the bottom or if opening it at the bottom would require making the options popup scrollable.

Is there a specification somewhere listing all the features the native select widget supports?

I'm aware the implementations might be platform-dependent, but it would be useful to have docs for any of them.

The best I could find was information on a similar component - `combobox`:

- https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/ComboBox+User+Experience+Documentation
- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#combobox
- https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html

Answer (score 5):

In the HTML terminology, it's called the *select element*.

You can find its specification in the [HTML 5.2
W3C Recommendation, section 4.10.7](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-select-element)

You can also look at the same section in working draft of the [upcoming HTML 5.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-select-element).